# Is there a difference between the first 446 bytes of different windows MBRs?

Tags: windows, mbr

After reading a lot about install algorithms for installing windows from linux, for installing linux in addition to windows, .... I'm wondering a bit.

From what I read for example for installing windows from linux most methods create a copy (or their own) MBR out of the first 446 bytes of a windows MBR and use that 
then to set the first 446 bytes of the MBR on the computer where windows shall be installed (or to restore those 446 bytes in case something goes awry).

Now what intrigued me is that there is a linux program called ms-sys (on sourceforge thus open source) that can be used for win xp, win 7, .... To create such appropriate MBR backups.

And after reading something on the net that the first 446 bytes are a leftover from MSDOS (so to say) I'm wondering the following:

Does the MBR (the first 446 bytes only) for the different windows versions (XP, windows 7, windows 8, ...) have any differences? *Or can these 446 bytes of a windows XP be used for a windows 7 (or vice versa).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think they are probably different.  Some checking does indicate that, yes, they are different.

I don't expect much difference in their behavior.  The basic job of those 446 bytes is to identify another section of the disk that has additional code to be executed.  That additional code is typically stored inside a partition.  Some people like to use a "boot loader", like [GAG](http://gag.sf.net) or the ones installable with XFDisk or RPM (Ranish Partition Manager) where the 446 bytes do something slightly different, like provide an interactive interface so the user can choose to pass control to a different partition.  Basically, this enables a "boot menu" so a person can easily choose to boot from a different operating system, enabling "multiboot" options (so a person can easily boot different operating systems).

That basic job likely hasn't changed much in quite a while.  (However, precise details about how it performs the functionality has been changed.)  If there have been any useful updates with newer operating systems, then I would imagine those updates to do something like supporting larger disk sizes.  Chances are quite good that the boot code of all recent Windows releases (including XP) may support up to 2TB, the limit of the MBR format.

(I should note that this answer was intended to address systems relying on the "MBR" for basic partitioning info.  Systems that use GPT may also have an MBR which needs to fulfill specific requirements specified by the GPT standard.)

**Update**

I have to conclude that different versions of Windows do have some differences in the first 446 bytes.  The most compelling documentation I found so far is [TechNet: Windows Vista details: Bootsect Command-Line Options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749177%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which shows that the user can specify /nt52 or /nt60 switches to install different versions of boot code.

There might be more, too.  It looks like [MSDN: Advanced format (4K) disk compatibility update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) " was released for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. This update contains much new info, some of which is applicable only to Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012."  I haven't yet confirmed whether the first 446 bytes were also changed for these changes, but the possibility does seem strong since changes were made to permit the boot process to have different hardware compatibility.

If you want more details about what is in the 446 bytes, I did locate some documentation about some older versions.  [Win2K boot sector details](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976796.aspx) is an older document, which is newer than [MS KB 140418: boot sector for Win NT 3.x](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/140418).

Comment: From how I understand it windows has the partition part after those first 446 bytes. So the partitioning info shouldn't be a problem there (or make a difference).  Question is though if those 446 bytes are different for each windows version (assuming though that C is the system drive each).

Comment: @Thomas: As I mentioned in the earlier version of my answer, "I'd have to do some further checking to be sure."  I have now done enough checking to confirm that there are some known differences, as shown in text that I have now updated in that answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are (minor) differences in the mbr code installed by different Windows versions. They all check the partition table to find which is the bootable partition and then transfer control to the first sector of that partition. So the different versions are largely interchangeable. See for instance the pages at http://thestarman.narod.ru/asm/mbr/VistaMBR.htm#INTRO . There's nothing particular to Windows in that kind of mbr code, it could just as well boot any other operating system. The MBR code installed by many Linux boot managers, such as GRUB, is completely different, and may not even look at the partition table at all, and would be useless in a system that does not have the GRUB boot files stored in a Linux partition, or its own special boot partition.

The newer GPT/UEFI boot procedure is a whole different world.

Comment: So the 446 bytes are different between the different windows versions and thus it would be unwise to use a win xp one for win 7 and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

The question "Are these two MBRs different?" is **not** equivalent to the question "Can I  use a MBR of one Windows version on a different Windows version?".

There are some differences between MBRs of different Windows versions. The most extensive online reference I know is [the Starman's Web page](http://thestarman.narod.ru/asm/mbr/index.html).

In [the page about Win2000/WinXP's MBR](http://thestarman.narod.ru/asm/mbr/Win2kmbr.htm#DC) it is stated:

> The first 300 bytes (000h through 12Bh) of this 512-byte sector are executable code...

while in [the page about Windows 7/8's MBR](http://thestarman.narod.ru/asm/mbr/W7MBR.htm#DC) we can read:

> The first 355 bytes (000h through 162h) of this 512-byte sector are executable code

and later:

> But this code must first copy itself into another area of Memory. This is necessary because the code must also load the Boot Sector of the Active Partition into the same area of Memory that it occupies just after being loaded! Unlike the Windows 2000/XP MBR, this code copies all 512 of its bytes to the new location, starting at: 0000:0600. Only the first three instructions are the same as the Windows 2000/XP MBR, so keep your eyes sharp if you're comparing the two.

This shows there are differences between the two.

Yet TheStarman states (I have never tried this myself, that's why I am simply reporting this), for both MBRs above:

> **Note**: Like all other code presented in this series, this MBR code could still be used to boot any OS on an x86 PC if it meets the conditions listed [here](http://thestarman.narod.ru/asm/mbr/Win2kmbr.htm#multi).

And then:

> Even though we're examining code created by a Microsoft Operating System, this MBR can also be used to start the boot process for any operating system's Boot Record on an x86-CPU based (PC) computer as long as that OS is: 1) on the Primary Master hard drive, 2) set to be the only Active partition and 3) it has a boot loader in the first sector of that partition.

Lastly, I should mention that the same Web pages report whole versions of all MBRs (except for the partition table, of course), which may in any case be helpful in restoring a lost/corrupted MBR. The standard partition table can be reconstructed by hand, or with instruments also provided by TheStarman's web pages.

Comment: You got +1 from me as it is a good point with the two being different not being the same as the two being able to be used interchangeably. Also interesting additional infos there!

Comment: "Can I use a MBR of one Windows version on a different Windows version?" - in the context of that question, it bears repeating that apart from the mbr code, this 512 byte sector also holds part of the partition table (the rest is distributed across the spaces between partitions as a linked list of further 512 byte sectors of similar structure), so exchanging that whole sector (as many tools would do) can have interesting side effects.

Comment: @rackandboneman That's why I said: **except for the partition table, of course**. I doubt I  could have been more explicit.

Comment: In addition to that the partition table seemingly starts AFTER the 446 bytes and takes up the rest of the boot sector. (at least from what I had read 446 was everything aside from the partition table part and that 446 bytes is what I was confused about)